# iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, url-scheme, uiapplication

I've recently discovered the awesome *iOS5 custom Settings URL Scheme*, which can be explained in detail at this great [website](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-settings-app).

I've found this to work, directing the user to the Settings app from my application:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
       [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
```

But cannot seem to route directly to the **Restrictions** path via the `path` parameter:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
   [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Restrictions"]];
```

Has anyone found documentation on this or been able to make this work?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to take the user to enable in-App purchasing, and would rather not have the user manually click on Restrictions (not very obvious).

Comment: does anybody know the url for Touch ID & Passcode?

Comment: use this for touch id: prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410746/ios-prefs-url-scheme-for-touch-id-passcode-settings/35411090#35411090)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

AS [@Nix Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38825209/1168654)'s ANSWER THIS IS NOT WORK IN **IOS 10**

---

**WARNING: This method will not work for devices running iOS 5.1 and greater - See Hlung's comment below.**

It's possible that the `path` component has a different name than the actual section, but it's also possible that you can't currently access that section straight from a URL. I found a list of possible URLs and Restrictions is not on it, maybe it's just not found out yet.

List of currently known URLs in the Settings app:

- prefs:root=General&path=About
- prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
- prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
- prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
- prefs:root=Brightness
- prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
- prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
- prefs:root=FACETIME
- prefs:root=General
- prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
- prefs:root=CASTLE
- prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
- prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
- prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
- prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
- prefs:root=MUSIC
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
- prefs:root=General&path=Network
- prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
- prefs:root=NOTES
- prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
- prefs:root=Phone
- prefs:root=Photos
- prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
- prefs:root=General&path=Reset
- prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
- prefs:root=Safari
- prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
- prefs:root=Sounds
- prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
- prefs:root=STORE
- prefs:root=TWITTER
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
- prefs:root=VIDEO
- prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
- prefs:root=Wallpaper
- prefs:root=WIFI
- prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING

Comment: Henri, thanks for your prompt response.  This is a much more verbose listing of url schemes for Settings that I was able to find.  I'll be sure to do some research and post back if I can find anything specifically regarding the "Restrictions" path.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem, if you end with the same list as I did, make sure to mark my answer as accepted to let others also know.

Comment: Is there any official documentation on this?

Comment: Didn't find any about the available URLs, only about how the URLs work. This list is put together from different sites.

Comment: Of course, as URL schemes for the Settings app were introduced with iOS 5, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: https://github.com/Burnsoft/Settings-Swipe an open source project I added to github may be of interest to those looking for shortcuts to settings. Nik

Comment: Worth noting that apple will reject any apps that use or make reference to the prefs URL scheme.

Comment: @NikBurns do you have any reference for that?

Comment: only from experience with AppStore review process. rdar://5864941 if you want to dupe it.

Comment: Has anyone come across the URL for the `Mail, Contacts, Calendar | Fetch New Data` settings?

Comment: Just a kind warning, http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/29/iphone-5-1-disables-shortcuts/ said that **all url schemes to iOS settings will be removed in iOS5.1** (so urls like prefs:root=General&path=Network will no longer work) So, please aware.

Comment: They are not completely removed you just have to put these URL links in a button in an UIAlertView.  So simply put a warning in the UIAlertView that the app will go to background and settings will open and then OK, and Cancel etc.

Comment: @zambono Can you confirm this is working and apps are being approved/functioning properly across a variety of devices and iOS versions?

Comment: It's no longer working, it was working on one of my apps a while back but not anymore.

Comment: As of iOS8 you can launch the built-in Settings app with the url: `[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]`

Comment: It is worth noting that the last snippet takes you to the app specific privacy settings and not just the settings app.

Comment: @JasonMoore is there a way to open this settings using a link (using HTML/JS) ?

Comment: This was re-added in iOS 9. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399893/open-phone-settings-programmatically-in-ios9

Comment: @FabianKöbel The url for Touch ID & Passcode is 'TOUCHID_PASSCODE' (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35411090/4493512) , but not sure if this is not to be rejected when publishing.

Comment: @MaggiePhillips thank you. We've already launched apps with this, it was no reason to reject them.

Comment: @FabianKöbel Ow, did you succeed in launching your app using 'prefs:root=TOUCHED_PASSCODE' ?? then I will right away use it.

Comment: @MaggiePhillips yes, these apps are already available in the App Store. It was no problem.

Comment: Working fine in iOS 9.2.3 
Check URL Scheme :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: Any solution/alternative for ios10 please.

Comment: Is this legit? Successful app submission doesn't mean that this is legit. It may fail eventually in the future.. is there any proofs?..can't find..

Comment: Almost all of these are undocumented, thus should not really be used without being ready for them to break.

Comment: Working if you change prefs to App-prefs, like:

App-prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP

But is this legal ?

Comment: `App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth` is working for me in iOS 10 but I am not sure, it is legit or not

Comment: App-Prefs:root=GAMECENTER  is working on 10.3.3 (14G60) [updated today]

Comment: @MichaelGarito Yes man! It's really working perfectly! Thanks you are save my time!

Comment: iOS 10, Location Services shortcut = `App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION`

Answer (score 48):

As of iOS8 you can open the built-in Settings app with:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

The actual URL string is `@"app-settings:"`. I tried appending different sections to the string ("Bluetooth", "GENERAL", etc.) but seems only linking to the main Settings screen works. Post a reply if you find out otherwise.

Comment: That's because that particular call is the Settings Launch URL. It opens the app's custom settings if they exist. If not, it just opens the Settings app to the main screen. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Settings_Launch_URL

Comment: Fantastic answer if your app has specific settings you want enabled/disabled. All in one place and don't have to navigate the user through Settings to get to desired configuration. Thanks!

Comment: @FabianKöbel were you able to find one for TouchID & Passcode?

Comment: @AspersionCast : you can use this: prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410746/ios-prefs-url-scheme-for-touch-id-passcode-settings/35411090#35411090)

Comment: This appears to be the only currently-Apple-approved method to launch the Settings app.

Comment: Nope Apple rejected our app because of this "prefs:"

Answer (score 42):

If you add the prefs URL scheme to your iOS app, it will allow you to use all those schemes that we could in iOS 5. I've tested it on iOS 9, but I think it will work on older versions too.

[image]

Comment: This trick only works starting iOS 8 where there's no need for it.

Comment: But same in iOS 8 you are not allowed to open WiFi settings, for example, if you don't add this URL shame to your application.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Didn't think about this use case.

Comment: @conorgriffin For you and anyone else wondering the setting lives under: Targets | (Application) | Info | URL Types | +

Comment: Someone said he got rejected for using "prefs:root" url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme#comment56751438_33896318

Answer (score 34):

Update:

`prefs:` will NOT work since iOS 10.

Comment: What's the alternative ?

Comment: That's crazy, since this official Apple Doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1924/_index.html) purposely addressees the prefs issue, and dated 8/2/2016.

Comment: That doc does say only to use it for keyboard settings  (anything other than that specific use is a violation.)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work even for keyboard settings in iOS 10.

Comment: Is there a reason why they removed it? Or is it a bug? If so, should report it as a [bug to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: hey, it is true that this doesn't work anymore on iOS10 but what is funny is, that apps like google maps / apple maps when you disable location services in settings and try to call the function "navigate" in these apps, both apps are able to open settings / location services even on iOS 10 :).. hackers, or i don't know (no wonder in case of apple app, but in case of google maps..)

Comment: @ Nix Wang , Any other method or alternative possible for prefs: in iOS 10.

Comment: While `prefs:` no longer work, the following does (at least in opening general): `App-Prefs::root=Settings&path=General`

Comment: Alternative is `App-Prefs:` from iOS 10 on wards.

Answer (score 22):

Yep, saw this (and many more), even implemented it in a test application. Really need to get the definitive word from Apple, but the community consensus opinion is Apple disallowed it in 5.1 after it was publicly "discovered/published", so applications containing it won't be accepted.

**08/01/12 Update:** Asked Apple through my developer account if there is a way to programmatically launch the WiFi Settings dialog. Here is the response:

> "Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that
>   there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given
>   the currently shipping system configurations."

Comment: I recommend anyone who needs this feature to log an official bug report. The more it is reported, the more it will be visible and a better chance that a supported solution may be presented in the future. http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 18):

In **iOS 9** it works again!

To open **Settings > General > Keyboard**, I use:

```
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
```

Moreover, it is possible to go farther to **Keyboards**:

```
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS
```

Comment: I just noticed this in the PopKey app.  I tried the url for Settings > Wi-Fi settings and it works as well.  Let's hope this remains.

Comment: Do these schemes need to be added to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `info.plist`?

Comment: No, they don't. Just use its with openURL: method.

Comment: I am trying to use this to link to settings from a web page and it appears to work in Safari on an iPhone but not an iPad. Both are on 9.0.2. Seriously, Apple?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'll also try to check this case and respond you.

Comment: Still needed to add prefs URL scheme to target

Comment: This works in the simulator for me but not on the device. iOS 9.1.

Comment: Well, it's very strange because I've checked this feature right now on my iPhone 5S with iOS 9.1 onboard, and it works as usual.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on an 5th gen iPod touch running iOS 9.0.2. I added `prefs` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and `canOpenURL:` returns `NO` for any URL starting with `prefs:`. And `openURL:` does nothing.

Comment: Hi Mikhail Gasaonov,
I have tried it in iOS 9.1 as per your post but its not working...
     
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];`

Comment: This code works fine on iPhone 5, 5S, 6 and 6 Plus (with iOS 9+), but not on the latest iPhone 6S and 6S Plus.

Comment: [Here in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37432131/3541063) people say this cause **rejection** on review process.

Comment: We have been using this successfully to link to Wi-Fi settings and have been accepted into the App Store twice. Unfortunately, it is no longer working with iOS 10 Beta 1.

Comment: > Important: The prefs: URL scheme is undocumented. Its use, except in the specific case described in this document, is a violation of the iOS App Review Guidelines and may result in the rejection of your app. You may only use the specific URL scheme in Listing 1 to open the Keyboard settings, and only from a custom keyboard extension. It may not be used by any other type of app, nor to open any other Settings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1924/_index.html

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to open the Bluetooth Menu in the Settings Application and the above path (prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth) didn't work for me. 
What ended up working for me was

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=Bluetooth")!)
```

Make sure you have the `prefs` URL Scheme defined first.

Comment: This is because the Bluetooth menu has been moved around in recent iOS versions. It's now a top-level setting, not under **General**.

Comment: @Imran: You forgot the `prefs`-stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Solution for iOS10. Works fine.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-prefs:root=TWITTER"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Is this legit? Successful app submission doesn't mean that this is legit. It may fail eventually in the future..

Comment: @Stas : No, it's not, since it is a private API.

Comment: > Important: The prefs: URL scheme is undocumented. Its use, except in the specific case described in this document, is a violation of the iOS App Review Guidelines and may result in the rejection of your app. You may only use the specific URL scheme in Listing 1 to open the Keyboard settings, and only from a custom keyboard extension. It may not be used by any other type of app, nor to open any other Settings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1924/_index.html

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS10 you can use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root")!)
```

to open general settings.

also you can add known urls(you can see them in the most upvoted answer) to it to open specific settings. For example the below one opens touchID and passcode.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE")!)
```

Comment: "App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE" doesn't work on iOS 11. Any other solution?

Comment: `App-Prefs` is a private API which will lead to app rejection during review.

Comment: > Important: The prefs: URL scheme is undocumented. Its use, except in the specific case described in this document, is a violation of the iOS App Review Guidelines and may result in the rejection of your app. You may only use the specific URL scheme in Listing 1 to open the Keyboard settings, and only from a custom keyboard extension. It may not be used by any other type of app, nor to open any other Settings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1924/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is something else I found:

1. After I have the "prefs" URL Scheme defined, **"prefs:root=Safari&path=ContentBlockers"** is working on Simulator (iOS 9.1 **English**), but not working on Simulator **(Simplified Chinese)**. It just jump to Safari, but not Content Blockers. If your app is international, be careful.
   Update: Don't know why, now I can't jump into ContentBlockers anymore, the same code, the same version, doesn't work now. :(
2. On real devcies (mine is iPhone 6S & iPad mini 2), **"Safari" should be "SAFARI"**, "Safari" not working on real device, "SAFARI" now working on simulator:

   ```
   #if arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
       // Simulator
       let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Safari")!
   #else
       // Device
       let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=SAFARI")!
   #endif

   if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
       UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
   }
   ```
3. So far, did not find any differences between iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Did you ever get this working again? Such a shame if not!

Comment: @RyanBrodie What do you mean by "such a shame"?

Comment: That it's very unfortunate, would be great to link directly into Safari's Content Blocker settings

Comment: @RyanBrodie Even if it could works, I suggest you don't use it for App Store Apps right now, I just got a "rejected" from iTunes Connect this morning, for "prefs:root" is a private API ( there are apps using prefs:root on App Store ... God know why)

Comment: I didn't realise that thank you very much for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Works Fine for App Notification settings on IOS 10 (tested)

```
if(&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10

Use `app-prefs:`

```
App-prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA_SETTINGS_ID
```

See [gist](https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560)

Comment: > Important: The prefs: URL scheme is undocumented. Its use, except in the specific case described in this document, is a violation of the iOS App Review Guidelines and may result in the rejection of your app. You may only use the specific URL scheme in Listing 1 to open the Keyboard settings, and only from a custom keyboard extension. It may not be used by any other type of app, nor to open any other Settings.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1924/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

In iOS16 / Swift 5 to jump certain subsetting view, e.g. Battery setttings:

```
  if let url = URL(string: "App-prefs:BATTERY_USAGE") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url) { accepted in
        print(accepted ? "Success" : "Failure")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am updating one news here.
Using 'prefs:' only is NOT rejected by Apple, I tested it and checked approved to the app store(in Aug, 2016). thx.

Comment: i am using this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB"]];` for open DND Setting of device. Apple will reject this ?

Comment: Had it  only passed the review or does it also works? I mean does the openURL takes you to settings? It did not work on my side.