# Access iPhone Location Services with phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova

Is it possible to access iPhone location settings with phonegap?

What i want to do is provide a link from the App to "Settings -> Location Services"

Thanks

**SOLVED**
I did a quick test and this works:

```
<a href="prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS 5.0 you can open the Settings application by using the `prefs://` "protocol". This will not work on versions earlier than iOS 5.

Edit: you should also be able to specify where in the settings application by using that type of URL, just to clarify.

Comment: No reason that it wouldn't if the other URL schemes work, given that the app is compiled for iOS 5, etc.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. In the iOS5 SDK beta the Settings URL's were undocumented and stayed that way when carried over to the iOS5 release. Applications using this method would run the risk of rejection from the App Store.

Comment: I based my answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme). As far as I'm aware, other apps (in the App Store) use it, so I wouldn't expect it was a problem.