# In app link to Settings -> 'Location Services' in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, core-location

There is a view in my app dependent on location services.

If the location manager delegate is alerted that the user has denied location services for my app, then I want this view to display a short message (along the lines of "Location services need to be enabled to... etc") and have a button that takes the user to the Settings app, specifically to the 'Location Services' option.

I know have a link to Settings was not previously possible with iOS, but can it now be done with iOS 5?

Comment: Yes you're right, this is a duplicate of the above question.

Comment: Find a list of known urls of the settings app in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme