# Are deep links to iOS Settings now officially supported?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

A while ago someone said it's possible to send a user to a specific page in the Setting app of iOS. Then I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041526/in-app-link-to-settings-location-services-in-ios-5) on Stack Overflow where some say Apple removed this great feature in iOS 5.1, which I can hardly believe.

Did they just replace this URL scheme with something else? Or is there no official way to send a user to a specific Settings page?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is still no officially supported way to do this in iOS 6. Sorry. I think Apple want to reserve the right to alter the Settings without apps breaking.