# launch settings from alert

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to launch settings app from an alert like you see below:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

```
if([title isEqualToString:@"Ok"])
{
    NSLog(@"Ok was selected.");
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Safari"])
{
    NSLog(@"open Safari was selected.");
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
}
```

}

I used prefs:root=General, but then I read from the link below...

[iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

...that this is not possible in ios5.1. Infact it does not work in the simulator. what can I do?? Thanks for the help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this (works on iOS 5 and up):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Comment: This was deprecated in iOS 5.1. In iOS 6.x still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Assistant "]];
```

List of currently known URLs in the Settings app:

```
prefs:root=General&path=About
prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
prefs:root=Brightness
prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
prefs:root=FACETIME
prefs:root=General
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
prefs:root=CASTLE
prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
prefs:root=MUSIC
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
prefs:root=General&path=Network
prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
prefs:root=NOTES
prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
prefs:root=Phone
prefs:root=Photos
prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
prefs:root=General&path=Reset
prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
prefs:root=Safari
prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
prefs:root=Sounds
prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
prefs:root=STORE
prefs:root=TWITTER
prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
prefs:root=VIDEO
prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
prefs:root=Wallpaper
prefs:root=WIFI
prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING
```