# Turning on WiFi Settings from UIAlertView

Tags: ios, wifi

In the Facebook app of iOS when the user open the app without turning on Wi-Fi, there is a UIAlertView pops up,

```
Location Accuracy

Turning on Wi-Fi will improve location accuracy.

Settings     Ok
```

How can I detect this Wi-Fi on/off in iOS & also I want to redirect to the settings page of Wi-Fi settings to user to turn on Wi-Fi. I have seen lot of people told that it's not possible to do redirecting to settings page. But in this Facebook app it is possible. How can I do it in my app??

Comment: That is a system alert. It has nothing to do with the Facebook app (or any other app).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Settings from App (like Twitter to turn on Wi-Fi) - With iOS 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460928/open-settings-from-app-like-twitter-to-turn-on-wi-fi-with-ios-7-1)

Comment: The Facebook App uses location services, and as @rmaddy said, the system will issue the alert when location services are used and Wi Fi is off.  There is nothing you can do to trigger that alert (unless you are using location services).  You can detect whether the current Internet connection is via WiFi or WWAN (3G/4G) using Reachability but not whether Wi Fi is on but not connected to the Internet