# URL scheme of notification settings for a specific app?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I found that

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]];
```

goes to notification settings. Can I go into the notification settings of my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access, for example, mail notifications using :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=Mail"]];
```

Use the bundle display name of your app in the path, instead of Mail.

**Warning** : This doesn't work anymore under iOS 5.1 (thanks smparkes for the comment)

Comment: Sweet. Do you know of a good reference for these URL schemes? I googled earlier to try to answer this question, but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: @yuji check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

Comment: Even if bundle display name contains space?

Comment: None of this works with iOS 5.1 and has been mentioned as causing app store rejections.

Answer (score 0):

Using bundle identifier for your app

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=com.my.app"]];
```