# how to programmatically open the WIFI settings in objective c in iOS9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9

I'm trying to access the WIFI settings through my application using Objective-C. But can not find any way. Could someone help me?

Already tested with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

Does not work on iOS 9.

Comment: You can't since iOS5.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme

Comment: This is an English-only website. Please translate (Use http://translate.google.com if needed). Or use [Stackoverflow Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Este é um Inglês-only website. Por favor, traduzir (Use http://translate.google.com se necessário). Ou use [Stackoverflow Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'm sorry, the translation was sent wrong.

Comment: I tried it on 9.1 and it works

Comment: @Fernando Garcia Corrochano. Please could you post your code to see what I did wrong?

Comment: This is my code (same as yours)                                  if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
                                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];   
                                 }                     Try to add prefs tu URL schemes like http://stackoverflow.com/a/31253743/3668465 did

Comment: @FernandoGarcíaCorrochano. -> My God, the code worked !!! Thank you very very very much !! Really to run the code have to add the "prefs" in the URL scheme. My friend please, mount a response with your solution so I can give an +

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is my code

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) { 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]; 
}
```

Try to add prefs to URL schemes like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253743/3668465 did

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126813/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-on-ios-10) post to get the solution

Comment: This is forbidden by the app store guidelines, I just had an app rejected by the review team for doing this:
"Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change."

Comment: We are no more supposed to use this way to open Wi-Fi. Apple rejects the binary.

Answer (score 7):

This works fine on iOS 10,

> Go to Targets --> (Application) --> Info --> URL Types --> +

In the `URL Schemes` write

> prefs

Then Call,

```
- (void)openWifiSettings
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Broken in iOS 10. Any fixes?

Comment: Yes, this is broken in iOS10

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126813/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-on-ios-10/42513576#42513576) works fine on iOS 10

Comment: We are no more supposed to use this way to open Wi-Fi. Apple rejects the binary.

Answer (score 7):

As per Apple's New Review standards, we are not supposed to use this way to open Wi-Fi Settings. I have been using this for long time in my app and recently Apple rejected with the below comment.

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a
>   private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App
>   Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs
>   change.

So you can just navigate to settings of the app by using UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString.

Swift Code:

```
if let settingsUrl = URL.init(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl)
                }
```

Comment: How does this help? This code just launches the settings for the app, it has nothing to do with the WiFi settings

Comment: Please read the answer properly! Apple no more suggests to navigate to the wifi settings page directly. It just restricts the user to go yo settings. Apple expects the user himself to navigate to corresponding settings page.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask is "how does this *code snippet* help". Your answer is correct and helpful, but the code snippet doesn't really help with jumping to the WiFi settings (because it's not possible at all anymore, I got that).

Answer (score 3):

All conditions:

```
    NSURL * urlCheck1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"];
    NSURL * urlCheck2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
    NSURL * urlCheck3 = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlCheck1])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlCheck1];
    }
    else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlCheck2])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlCheck2];
    }
    else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlCheck3])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlCheck3];
    }
    else
    {
        //Unable to open settings app.
    }
```

Comment: We are no more supposed to use this way to open Wi-Fi. Apple rejects the binary.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get straight to wifi setting with openURL.  All you can do is to open settings for your own app.

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil) {
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Its solution opens the application settings menu. What I'm wondering is how to open the WiFi settings menu.

Comment: Yes Yes. However, I have an application installed on my iPhone that does exactly what I'm looking for, his name is the "Launcher", you know? If this application can do, because we can not do the same?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Pre iOS 10
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url])
{   //iOS 10+
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"];
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: We are no more supposed to use this way to open Wi-Fi. Apple rejects the binary.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh noted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2, iOS 12**

This is the function that I'm currently using in my app for it:

```
extension UIApplication {

    ...

    @discardableResult
    static func openAppSetting() -> Bool {
        guard
            let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL)
            else {
                return false
        }

        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)
        return true
    }
}
```

Usage: `UIApplication.openAppSetting()`

I also used *non-public URL scheme*, such as: `prefs:root=`, but my app was rejected. So if you're trying to do more specific stuff with deeplinking, don't waste your time because at the moment you can't!

Answer (score -6):

You can use this option:

iOS >= 4.1 it's possible to obtain SSID of wireless network that device is currenctly connected to.

For this you'd use function [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009770-CH101-SW4)

Details on implemenation: [iPhone get SSID without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library/5198968#5198968)

Comment: How does this explain how to open the WiFi settings page in the Settings app on iOS?