# Show avaiable wifi connections nearby

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Can I display the list of wifi access points on UI dialog & allow user to switch wifi settings from within my app by using swift 3?

OR

Is it possible to open the wifi settings on a prompt dialog which does not cover full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. [Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36303575/3589771)
[It may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671300/3589771)

### Objective C

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"]];
}
```

### Swift

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "prefs:root=WIFI")) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "prefs:root=WIFI"))
}
else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=WIFI"))
}
```