# Opening IOS settings preferences

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings, preferences

Im having a problem opening the settings preferences in my IOS iphone app. At the moment im just using a simple button to test and it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Basically when I click the button I want a specific settings preference page to open. This is what Im currently using within my buttons IBACTION:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]];
```

Hope you guys can help me out with a solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: This only works in iOS `5.0`. The prefs shortcuts were removed in 5.1. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme

Comment: Oh so this cannot be used in IOS 5.1 at all ? I mean, it has been completely removed ?

Comment: Yes, completely removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

should work in iOS 5

... update:

```
opening with the prefs url was disabled in iOS 5.1
```

sebastian

Comment: Hi sebastian, Ive just tried that, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: hi, sorry to bring the news, i figured out that this way was blocked with iOS 5.1... let us know if you find another solution =)