# Any other alternatives to open Settings page in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, settings

Since from 5.1 OS we cant launch settings page programmatically. Guys can anyone suggest me other alternatives or api's to open Settings page in iOS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening IOS settings preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055853/opening-ios-settings-preferences)

Comment: You cannot do this with public APIs. You can replicate your applications preferences in your own app. If you want to launch system preferences there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Agree . I basically wanted to launch Facebook and twitter pages from system preferences. Thanks Paul..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use  [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com) which does the replication for you.

Since iOS 5.1, there is no official way to open Settings via App.

[Here to Go.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)