# Can an app include a page where a user can control the apps' permissions?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am writing a cross-platform app in Xamarin. The app requires certain permissions or it is pretty well useless.

We want to make it as easy as possible for the user to manage the apps permissions.

In iOS the permissions can be accessed on a per app basis (General then scroll to the list of apps at the bottom of the screen, tap and control all the permissions for that app) or a user can grant/revoke access to one particular permission. For example, the user can go to "Cellular Data" and control which apps can use cellular data and which cannot.

That was always a bit unclear to me, so it makes more sense now.

Ideally I would like to put the screen below into the Settings of my app. So there would be a little gear icon for Settings and one option in Settings is "Permissions" and tapping that would show the screen below (in essence). That would be easier to the user I believe.

OK, if we cannot do that can we still have the permissions entry and it would take the user right to the screen below?

Thank you very much,

Bryan

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this. The OS controls permissions.  Use the Permissions plugin to prompt the user to grant permissions on-demand, but if they don't then they have to go to the OS settings to fix that.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at here [navigate-to-settings-screen-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549053/navigate-to-settings-screen-in-iphone).

Comment: I agree with what Jason has to say but if I am not wrong there is a way in which you can directly jump to your apps settings and the user can then update the permissions there. I am sure you can do this in iOS not sure about android though

Comment: Jason, I wasn't clear. I understand I cannot change the settings just by the user toggling the switch or selecting something. I want to put some text below each "Permission" indicating a) why we want to use the permission and b) what the setting should be [if it is not a binary] and c) something like tap on the item above to set the permission. If the user does this then my preference is to ask the OS to change this to what I want, and then the OS will pop-up and agree or not. If I cannot do that then just go to the permissions area in the Settings app. I believe that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try navigating to the settings app in iOS using this :

```
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I appreciate it.