# How do I move to iPhone settings from an app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created an app,When a user clicks button for twitter sync,It will show an action sheet of twitter accounts in the phone settings
If there is no any accounts,it will show an alert view.How can i move to phone settings(specially creation of twitter accounts) from click on that alert OK button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not allow doing that via code. You need to popup a dialog and request user to do this manually. Not nice, I know...

It used to be possible, but Apple has now blocked it. More details at [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

Comment: Yep, used to be possible. I added a link to article with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping to the settings app using a custom url scheme happened to work prior to iOS5.1, but was never officially supported. I've filed a DTS to get an official answer.

> Thank you for your inquiry to Apple Worldwide Developer Technical
>   Support. I am responding to let you know that I have received your
>   request for technical assistance.
>
> The URL scheme to launch Settings app or to a certain screen in
>   Settings has never been documented nor supported. Staring with iOS
>   5.1, Apple has removed support for linked-to system preferences in iOS 5.1, the same with iOS 6.0
>
> If you want URL access support to Settings, please file a bug report
>   to "http://bugreporter.apple.com".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on iOS 5.0:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

But now moving to settings app is no more supported from application. you need to write custom message and alert user to go to setting and make particular thing enabled on/off.

Hope this info helps you..