# Open wifi settings with url schema

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, wif

I need to open wifi settings, I wrote this line

```
NSURL * appStoreUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @ "prefs: root = WIFI"];
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: appStoreUrl];
```

but it doen't work, i should add something else or ...? Maybe you can tell how can I open wifi -screen in my app. Thank you 
I use iOS 6.1. and

Comment: idownloadblog.com/2011/11/29/iphone-5-1-disables-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Try using it to access the WiFi settings in iOS 5.1

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

---

Try using it to access the WiFi settings in iOS 9

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) { 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]]; 
}
```

Try to add prefs tu URL schemes like [stackoverflow.com/a/31253743/3668465](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253743/3668465) did.

---

You can use this option for identify a SSID:

iOS >= 4.1 it's possible to obtain SSID of wireless network that device is currenctly connected to.

For this you'd use function [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](http://CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo)

Details on implemenation: [iPhone get SSID without private library](http://iPhone%20get%20SSID%20without%20private%20library)

---

question example -> [how to programmatically open the WIFI settings in objective c in iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437815/how-to-programmatically-open-the-wifi-settings-in-objective-c-in-ios9/33676848#33676848)

Answer (score 0):

In ios < 5.1 apple was supporting [shortcut urls](http://holgr.com/blog/2011/11/no-jailbreak-necessary-how-to-quickly-access-ios-settings-on-your-ipad-iphone-or-ipod/) like the one you described. But later for ios >= 5.1 apple [discontinued](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/11/apple-disables-home-screen-shortcuts-for-settings-toggles-in-ios-5-1.html) it.

Comment: and how can i now open wifi setting?

Comment: Lets see what others have to say.