# iOS: Open Wi-Fi Settings Screen programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I would like to prompt user to choose from exsiting Wi-Fi Networks. 
So I'd like to open Wi-Fi Settings Screen programatically. How is it done?

Comment: There isn't a public API to do so.

Comment: Yep, it was once possible, but apple removed the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no (public) API to do this - you would need to find the URL scheme for the Settings app, then figure out how to hack it to show the wifi screen.

Even if you could do this, your app would *probably* be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: This application does it and is on the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/launcher-notification-center/id905099592

Comment: @shim iOS 9's deep linking allows you to do that. That ability didn't exist when I wrote this answer (at which point we were on iOS 6).

Comment: As far as I can tell it uses private URL schemes. Shows these kinds of strings in the app http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences.app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme