# Is there any way to show Settings app in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, nsurl

I want to show defaul Settings app. Before I could use method

```
NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
```

But now it's disabled, is there any way now in iOS7 to show Settings app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is ***not*** possible anymore, as apps were offering jailbreak like solutions through the app store(Settings shortcuts). See the following link [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme). Infact, its been disable since iOS **5.1**.

See the following link for an article that shows when and why this was removed in detail: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/29/iphone-5-1-disables-shortcuts/