# Open Setting App from my applicaiton in iPhone iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, location, settings

I want to open `iphone default setting` application form my `application`, Please any one tell me what I have to do. OR is there any code to open it.

I try following code but it dont works.in `iOS 7.1.`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES_Systemservices"]];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This works in iOS 5.0 and below only

Answer (score 2):

For iOS8 and later use :

```
// Send the user to the Settings for this app
//iOS 8 only
NSURL *settingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settingsURL];
```

Comment: The question is specifically for iOS 7.

Comment: Also, OP asked for how to go to the default settings page, whereas the method provided here brings you to an app-specific settings page.

Comment: I successfully submitted an app using this method last month.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5.1, there is no official way to open Settings via App.

[Here to Go.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

Comment: I need to open it in ios7.

Comment: but you can't do it below iOS 5.1 version :)

Comment: are you getting deprecated warning using your code.

Comment: This changed in iOS 8. However for iOS 7 there doesn't seem to be a public way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use private API to open Settings App from your application. But i'm not sure if it will get accepted from apple.

```
void (*openApp)(CFStringRef, Boolean);
void *hndl = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices", 0);
openApp = dlsym(hndl, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
openApp(CFSTR("com.apple.Preferences"), FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
       UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
```