# How to open Notification Center via URL Scheme from app?

Tags: objective-c

Using the URL Scheme below, I'm able to open the 'Settings' App from the app I'm currently working on.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Is it also possible to tweak the URL Scheme so that I can directly open the 'Notification Center' feature inside the 'Settings' App?

Kindly advise. All help appreciated!

Comment: You will see the Notification settings for your current app if you use that URL scheme, though. (If you have registered your app for notifications, of course.)

Comment: Agreed and thanks for the quick response. 
Moving on, any way to access the 'Notifications' feature of a particular app inside the 'Settings' App using URL Schemes ? Which means having a reduced number of clicks to reach destination ?

Comment: Not that I know of, sadly.

Comment: Likewise. Thanks anyway Glorfindel :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code to prevent crashes from iOS versions and it's working for me:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(openURL:options:completionHandler:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tested on iOS 8 up;

you can try this url scheme: *"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"*
But u must add **URL types** in ur project: Click on ur Project in **Project Navigator**-> click on **TARGET** -> tab **Info** -> and add **URL Types** by click (**+**) and add **URL scheme** : *"prefs"*.

if you still not clear check this [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

All the best,