# How to open general settings (not in the app settings) from the app in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, settings.bundle, custom-keyboard

I know about this

```
    if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
    NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
}
```

But I wanna know if its possible to go to the general settings. I need users to enable the keyboard but landing in the app settings confused many users. Any suggestions to open the general settings and even if possible the keyboards section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open system apps in iOS. You can show them the path to the message though.

'Settings->General->Keyboard' etc in a modal whenever you wish to display this information to the user.

Comment: Thanks. I will then prepare a short tutorial.

Comment: It is possible with iOS 9.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32839330/496504).  Whether this was intentional by Apple or gets changed in a future iOS release remains to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 10 the one can use "App-Prefs:root" URL:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root"]];
```

Comment: Apple wil reject your app and potentially kick you off the store for using URLs such as "prefs:root=bluetooth" or "app-prefs:root=bluetooth".