# iOS prefs url scheme for touch id & passcode settings

Tags: ios, touch, settings, fingerprint, touch-id

there are a lot of lists with prefs urls for the iOS settings app, used to open a specific site in the settings app (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246814/4266294). Unfortunately, I cannot find the url in order to open the touch id & passcode settings.

Does anybody know the url scheme for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE") {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

this works on IOS 10.2. However I'm not sure if apple rejects this or not. Has anyone had any issues with their submission using this?

Comment: thanks! This solution works with iOS 10. There were no problems with the app store submission.

Comment: Never use `App-Prefs` it, I used it and Apple rejected my app.

Comment: @FabianKöbel My app has been rejected due to this (App-Prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE using apple private api)

Comment: Sorry everyone, this will cause apple to reject it as of now

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
prefs:root=TOUCHID_PASSCODE
```

Seen at http://www.appps.jp/126333/

Comment: Is this still working?? I guess this stops with iOS 10

Comment: Is this legit? Successful app submission doesn't mean that this is legit. It may fail eventually in the future..

Comment: This opened up the app's settings on iOS 11.

Comment: What's the Apple approved way then?