# What is the deep link format to navigate to iOS-settings app "Mobile Data" section

Tags: ios

I have to navigate the user to "Mobile data" section of settings app from my iOS app. To Open Wi-Fi, deep link is "prefs://root=WIFI". I need to know what is the value for "mobile Data" section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme)

Comment: While [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme) isn't an exact duplicate, the guts of the answer, in a very great deal of discussion, answer your question, as of iOS 5.1 this can no longer be done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is not any schema for Mobile Data.