# iOS 10 beta: URL scheme is not working but works in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10

In one particular scenario I am taking the user to passcode settings page . below is the code used for this -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=PASSCODE"]];
```

After upgrading to iOS 10 beta version  I am no longer taken to settings passcode page instead it terminates the app .

Can anyone please help me with this . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Opening preference pages apart from your own app's preferences has not been permitted for some time.  It seems that in iOS 10 Apple have further enforced this restriction.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 . As my clients are waiting on this , it would be grateful if you could also provide me more details on this , so that I can explain my clients the same .

Comment: Preferences URLs were removed in iOS 5.1.  I am surprised that your code has been working at all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme

Comment: Indeed and that is discussed in the answer I linked to, but that is not what you are trying to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No way yet.

About 1 month before iOS 10 beta 1 was released, my app got a rejection because of opening a Preference.app URL. The app review team gave me a phone call to explain it: It's not permitted right now for the reason: Using private API. Only opening current app's setting page(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) is allowed.

So it really makes sense now why they rejected me. Because no one could open system setting since iOS 10.

**Updated answer at 8 Dec, 2016:**

Using Private API (Don't submit the app with these code to the App Store):

```
@interface PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace
- (BOOL)openSensitiveURL:(id)arg1 withOptions:(id)arg2;
@end

PrivateApi_LSApplicationWorkspace* _workspace;

_workspace = [NSClassFromString(@"LSApplicationWorkspace") new];

BOOL result = (BOOL)[_workspace openSensitiveURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Prefs:root=YOURSETTINGURLHERE"] withOptions:nil];
```

Comment: Can you please send me the link of apple review process were this rule is mentioned because when I went through their documentation on review process I couldn't find this .

Comment: Sorry there's no link about it. The App Store Review Team gave me a phone call to explain it, and as you did, I asked where the rule is, in the review guideline or somewhere else? They just said, it's the rule, it's not written anywhere and that's why I give you a phone call to tell you it's a new rule, and the rule will not be public, at least not being public for now. BTW, it was really a terrible call, which feels like that "I'm your dad it's the rule because I say it's a rule".

Comment: Ah, good old Apple. Making their customers suffer since 2007.

Comment: It's not really a new rule as it falls under rule 2.5.1: Apps may only use public APIs. The problem is the MAY, should be a MUST ;-).

Comment: Did you have the solution in the end of 2016?

Answer (score 5):

The prefs scheme has changed on iOS 10, you can use this :

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string:"App-Prefs:root= PASSCODE")!, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly:true], completionHandler:{(success: Bool?) -> Void in}})
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL.init(string:"Prefs:root= PASSCODE")!)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

On iOS 10 you can use `openURL:options:completionHandler:` instead;

Also you can see this article([openURL Deprecated in iOS 10](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/?utm_campaign=CodeTengu&utm_medium=rss&utm_source=CodeTengu_61)) for more details.

Comment: thanks for link but it doesn't seem to solve anything