# iOS 9 app lunch URL for 'Storage and iCloud Usage'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication, appsettings

What is the openURL string for Settings > General > Storage and iCloud Usage
e.g. `prefs:root=General&path=???`

Comment: I have check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme
But `prefs:root=General&path=USAGE` is not working in iOS9

Answer (score 2):

The openURL string for `Settings > General > Storage and iCloud Usage` is:

`App-prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP`.

I have tested this on both iOS 9.2 and 10.3. Please note that it is `App-prefs` and not `prefs` in the URL scheme you define in URL Types under Info of your project settings.

Comment: Is this legal ? Will Apple reject this ?

Comment: @Ansari Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35987082/1023917. Apple will not reject this.

Comment: As per this thread, its not supported anymore by Apple, even though its working but there is no documented source available in iOS 10 SDK and above.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme/11218825#11218825

Comment: The one thread I linked to is a recent one, whereas the one you refer to is an earlier one. I don't have developer license, if you have one and you are in doubt, you can write to Apple Developer support and ask for sure.

Comment: Both of those threads are about `prefs:`, not `App-prefs:`. They are not relevant here. `App-prefs:` was added precisely because apps were using `prefs:` in ways that were not intended to be supported.