# Open iOS settings from the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

I am using this code to open `settings app` from my app. But is there any URL to open `Background App Refresh` settings from my app?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme but it won't work on iOS10 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you are not able to open any specific part in setting from your app. You are just able to redirect to user to those settings which are related to your app permission.