# Redirect to Settings root page in ios 8, 9 and 10

Tags: ios, appsettings, openurl

My question has been asked a lot of time and till now hasn't got a solution.
I'm trying to open Mobile data page from app.

1) I've tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]
```

In `iOS 8 and iOS 9`, instead of `root page`, it directly went to `Settings/AppName` page. This is not the behavior that I want. What I want is to enter Settings root page

2) as for `iOS 10`, the above method doesn't work. I've tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil]
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there any code that can satisfy both of the above. in `iOS` 8, 9  and 10, it will go to Settings root page (if possible, mobile data page). If there isn't any way, can provide link why it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**

in ios 8 and 9, by using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=GENERAL"]] i'm able to redirect to Settings Home page.

for ios 10.1.0 and below, using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA"]] will redirect to app specific page in Settings. but in the latest 10.1.1, it won't do anything.

I'm using Xcode 8.0.

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]] ` this should open `setting app` !! in which ios version are you testing ?

Comment: it open settings app but it entered the app specific settings page....i want it to enter Setting home page or if possible mobile data page

Comment: I am saying that it should open setting app's home page!!!

Comment: i'm testing in ios 8 and ios 9...it didn't open home page

Answer (score 1):

in iOS 10 they changed "prefs:" to "App-Prefs:"

```
    guard let profileUrl = URL(string: "App-    
     Prefs:root=General") else {
        return
    }

     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(profileUrl) {

     UIApplication.shared.open(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in

        print(" Profile Settings opened: \(success)")

        })
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: url types]

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root=General")!)
```

Other path:
[iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme/8246814#8246814)