# Open Settings Programmatically iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, settings, ios10

I am able to open Settings > iCloud using following method,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=CASTLE"]];
```

[image]

**Question:** Is this legal? Will Apple reject the application? Because I cannot find any legitimate source for this method to open iCloud Settings.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has stopped allowing redirection to the public schema like `Prefs` so from now on the application will not be able to redirect to the settings other than the self-settings.
[See the link for more detail](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49664)

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported officially and you can follow along this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme/8246814#8246814)
and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218825/5807290) in particular. Hope it clear out the issue. The settings would open but as it is not officially supported there may a rejection due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on experience, Apple will decline reviewing your app in case you use ":root=" non-public url Scheme

Apple Review Team Message:

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.