# How to programmatically launch the Phone section of Settings in iOS 11?

Tags: ios

The TrueCaller app programmatically launches the the Phone section of the Settings.
How does it perform that deep link into that part of the settings app?

Using a url of `prefs:root=General&path=XXX` used to work in older versions of the OS but neither prefs nor App-prefs appears to be working in iOS 11. ([iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme#comment56751438_33896318)) So how is TrueCaller managing to deep link directly into the Phone section of settings with iOS 11?

Comment: `App-Prefs:root=Phone&path=CallerID` works for me on iOS 11

Comment: @Paulw11 with iOS 11.1 that takes me to Settings but not to Settings|Phone.

Comment: I am on 11.2 and it takes me straight to the caller id and blocking preference

Comment: @Paulw11, what's your code? Have you added App-Prefs or something else to URL Types/ URL Schemes?

Comment: `guard let url = URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=Phone&path=CallerID") else {
                return
            }
            
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`  Nothing added to info.plist

Comment: Isn't `App-Prefs` a private API that might cause app rejection? Any better way to do this?