# Open Settings/Privacy/Photos for iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I couldn't use below code to open Settings/Privacy/Photos from iPhone X

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=PHOTOS"]];
```

But this code run well on other older devices

Answer (score 0):

after iOS 5.1 shortcuts are not working in devices. you can open setting page by following this code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Opened Settings");
        }
    }];
```

Comment: you can also see this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme/8246814#8246814